# How to show the selected item/values/details from modal in outside the modal using angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to show the values given in modal at outside the modal using AngularJS. [Plunker attached here](https://plnkr.co/edit/AGxy1U3RIkIRnHFKbXL9?p=preview) which clearly explains. Can anyone help me out........I have already checked Angular, Ui-Bootstrap site, but couldn't find the solution to the problem

**HTML**

```
   <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl as $ctrl" class="modal-demo">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">&times;</button><a>
                        <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title" style="color:red">Please Provide the Details Here</h3>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <form name="modalForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': modalForm.name.$invalid }">   <!--modalForm.name.$touched &&--> 
                            <a>*Name: </a><input name="name"  ng-minlength="3" 
    ng-maxlength="8" ng-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" size="10"  style="width: 50%" required />   


                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" ng-controller="ButtonsCtrl">
                            <a>*Gender: </a><pre>{{radioModel || 'null'}}</pre>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <label class="btn btn-success" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Male'" uncheckable>Male</label>
                                <label class="btn btn-success" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Female'" uncheckable>Female</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group" ng-controller="DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl">
                            <a>*Birth Date: Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></a><select class="form-control" ng-model="format" ng-options="f for f in formats" style="width: 50%"><option></option></select><input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" ng-required="true" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" style="width: 50%" />

                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <p ng-show="modalForm.modalPlace.$error.required">Select service</p>
                        </div>

                        </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.ok()" ng-disabled="modalForm.$invalid">OK</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$ctrl.open()">Open me!</button>

<div ng-show="$ctrl.selected">Name from the modal: {{ $ctrl.name }}</div>
<div ng-show="$ctrl.selected">Gender from the modal: {{ radioModel || 'null'}}</div>
<div ng-show="$ctrl.selected">DOB from the modal: {{ dt | date:'fullDate' }}</div>
```

Comment: where is `outside` modal??

Comment: You need to set the scope values again on the click of OK of modal using event or a service as your click event is in another controller.you have to update the scope values basically again.

Comment: as shown in plunker demo, below the button *Open me* @SaurabhAgrawal

Comment: Thanks, can you show me with plunker demo/Code @NamdeoKarande, bcz I dont have deep knowledge of Angular ..

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `modalInstance.result` property, it a promise which is resolved with a value when you close your modal (or rejects when you dismiss it).

The docs already provide you with a simple example

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
  $ctrl.selected = selectedItem;
}, function () {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

Inside your modal controller you can close/dismiss the modal using these methods

```
var selectedItem = ...
$uibModalInstance.close(selectedItem)
// or
$uibModalInstance.dismiss(selectedItem)
```

With `selectedItem` being passes to the controller that launched the modal.

Because you code is incomplete I can't really help you much more then that, the [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal) hold all you need to know really.

Comment: The [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal) not contains the information I needed. It contains only basics. How to hold *textbox/radiomodel/date* values and show the selected values outside the modal...Anyway, thanks for your reply